# unexpected problem of rendering mathematical set sign in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

I tried to render set sign in LaTeX, but it complained and raised a lot of errors. Here is what I want to render:

```
y_it∈ {ln GDP per capita, ln GVA per capita (by six sectors respectively)}


Td∈ [−6, −3) ℃
```

here is my code snippet:

```
$y_{it} \in \[ \left\{ $\ln_{GDP per capita}$, $\ln_{GVA per capita}$ (by six sectors respectively) \right\}\]$


$T_{d}$ \in $[-6, -3)\, ^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$
```

seems the compiler is not happy with above script, and I maybe made a mistake. Any quick solution to fix the error?

Comment: You mix two ways of writing math (using `$` and `\[ \]`) and you switch a lot between math mode and normal mode (at every `$`), which means that some code that is intended to be math is now normal text, which does not work. One way to clean it up is by putting one math delimiter at the start of every line and one at the end, and only math in between - although that may not give you the exact spacing and rendering that you are looking for.

Comment: @Marijn you mean the correct one would be `\[ \left\{ ...\right\}\]` or this one ` $y_{it}$ \in \[ \left\{ $\ln_{GDP per capita}$, $\ln_{GVA per capita}$ \right\}\]`? still doesn't work. Any further help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions

- Don't go in and out of math mode all the time
- Don't try to initiate display math mode when already in (normal, inline) math mode
- Use `\text` to typeset text snippets while in math mode. Don't typeset longer strings in the subscript position, where they'll be very difficult to read.
- Using `\left` and `\right` in the first row doesn't achieve anything. If you wish to enlarge the curly braces, write `\bigl\{` and `\bigr\}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
$y_{it} \in \bigl\{ \ln(\text{GDP per capita}), \ln(\text{GVA per capita, 
by 6 sectors resp.}) \bigr\}$

$T_{d} \in [-6, -3)\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: latex complain for this: `$T_{d} \in [-6, -3)\,^{\circ}\mathrm{C}$`, `^` must be inside math mode; why?

Comment: @datageek - As the screenshot shown above demonstrates, LaTeX had no problems compiling the code I posted. If you're getting warning or error messages from LaTeX, it must be because your code differs from mine in one or more aspects. E.g., did you maybe write `...-3\),^{\circ}...` instead of `...-3)\,^{\circ}...`? As you probably know, `\)` closes inline math mode...